# Tensorflow gives error when defining nce_loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient

I want to get the gradient for nce_loss. My code is as follows:

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.nce_loss(weights=weights,
                   biases=biases,
                   labels=ids,
                   inputs=datapoint,
                   num_sampled=10,
                   num_classes=220))

grads = tf.gradients(loss, datapoint)
```

But when defining the loss, I get the error:

> File "/path/fgsm.py", line 163, in 
>       main(config)   File "/path/fgsm.py", line 95, in main
>       num_classes=220),   File "/path/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py",
>   line 1248, in nce_loss
>       name=name)   File "/path/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py",
>   line 1031, in _compute_sampled_logits
>       if labels.dtype != dtypes.int64: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'

I don't understand what the error is here. The inputs of the loss formula should be accurate. num_classes is an int according to the api and it is an int as given by the example. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the given error message, you can see that it is talking about something about `labels`.

So I guess it's because that your `ids` is of type `list`. 
Maybe you should convert it to `numpy.ndarray` and then try again.